# How to send images to local windows clipboard from ssh connection?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, command-line, ssh, clipboard

I have an ssh connection to my other computer running Ubuntu. I want to be able to copy an image from a file, `example.png` and have it show up in the clipboard (not as text) and be able to paste it anywhere, such as GitHub or Discord.

Currently, I am using `ncat` to do this, but it only works for text files.
`ncat -klc "clip" localhost 10009` on windows
`ssh -R 10008:localhost:10009 192.168.1.3` to ssh
`ncat --send-only localhost 10008 < example.txt` to send the text output to the windows clipboard

Is there a way to do this using `ncat`, or perhaps even `xsel`?

Comment: Is using `sftp` an option?

Comment: i want to do the entire thing using only commands for automation purposes

Answer (score 1):

Install an X11 server on your local machine (like XWin from cygwin/x11, or X410, or Xming). Connect to the remote system with X11 forwarding enabled:

```
PS> $env:DISPLAY = "localhost:0"
PS> ssh -Y myserver
```

Then use `xclip` to copy the image to X11 clipboard in the correct format. On the X11 side, `image/bmp` is one that should work:

```
$ magick convert ~/foo.jpg bmp:- | xclip -in -sel clipboard -target image/bmp
```

(In both operating systems, multiple formats or ["targets" in X11 terminology](https://www.uninformativ.de/blog/postings/2017-04-02/0/POSTING-en.html) can be offered through the clipboard – the `xclip` tool only allows offering one target type at a time, but that's still better than `xsel` which doesn't allow changing the type it offers at all.)

The X11 server should then convert X11 formats to Windows formats. Unfortunately this doesn't work *correctly* for me with the X410 server (the bitmap data becomes misaligned during paste into Windows), but it's still the starting point.

Comment: i'm using xming, but when i run the last command, my clipboard is just blank